# Ubuntu.com download of ubuntu 12.10 failing

Tags: 12.10, downloads

I've been trying to download wubi as well as the normal iso for 12.10 and after 30 seconds of loading i get

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to glug.nith.ac.in
```

Is some known issue going on ?

Comment: Look like problem that mirror, try other mirrors :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your particular mirror (or your connection to it) may be having issues.

Assuming you're not trying to download it at work (where this option may be restricted, regardless of its use), one of the best options for downloading is the torrent download option on the [alternative downloads page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads). You can pick up T[ransmission for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trqtw/) (the Windows port of the Bit Torrent downloader used by Ubuntu) if you need a client.

Doing it this way allows you to connect to more than one different place to download it, eliminating connection issues and helping ease the pain of a flaky Internet connection.

However, I don't know if you can get Wubi this way (I've never used Wubi), but this will let you get the normal ISO file.

If you do need a direct download connection for whatever reason, you may be able to try one of the other mirrors, which are also listed on the alternative downloads page that I linked earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help at all, but because of my internet speed, I find FlareGet to make the best downloads.
It breaks the downloads up into segments and then downloads them individually